# req.files is undefined when uploading files for a dynamic page in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I upload images when I open a page , but when I open a dynamic page req.file is undefined.

dashController.js:

```
const storageEngine = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) { // cb => callback function
        var dir = './public/img/notes';
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) { fs.mkdirSync(dir) }
        cb(null, dir)
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, new Date().toDateString() + new Date().getTime() + file.originalname)
    }
})
var upload = multer({ storage: storageEngine }).array('images', 12)
var uploadadd = multer({ storage: storageEngine }).array('imagesNotes', 12)
```

There is no problem in uploading files by this page:

```
router.post('/dashboard/add', isLoggedIn, dashboardController.dashboardAddNoteSubmit);
```

add.ejs:

```
<form action="/dashboard/add" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="images" multiple class="files" accept="image/jpeg svg png jpg">
    <button type="submit">Add Images</button>
</form>
```

But when I open this dynamic page (For each note) I couldn't upload and req.file is undefined:

```
router.post('/dashboard/item/:id', isLoggedIn, dashboardController.dashboardUpdateNote);
```

update.ejs:

```
<form action="/dashboard/item/<%= noteID %>" method="POST">
 <input type="file" name="imagesNotes" multiple accept="image/jpeg svg png jpg">
   <button type="submit">Update</button>
  </form>
```

It seems that it doesn't read or see the upload file.

Comment: You are missing `enctype` attribute on your form tag. `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Yes, that was the reason, thank you.